# I can't write the opening square bracket "[" on zend studio

Tags: php, zend-studio

I can't write the opening square bracket "[" only on zend studio (I can everywhere else...)
I only install the "zen coding" plugin. Maybe there are some shortcut bind on these key (ALTgr + 5) ? up.

Comment: I suppose you have a non-US keyboard layout. I've seem Java apps where certain keys that require `AltGr` do not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem. For those who have the same problems, it's because of zen coding plugin.
Go to : 
- Window -> Preferences
- General tab -> Keys and type "[" in the "type filter text"
In my case I had one key binded on it, so I unbind it and now it works.